# Double tab bar in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

[image]

How do i solve this problem. I had used **isdtp=vw,,isdtp=mn,isdtp=lt** but these parameter changing new org to old org. This problem comes when i create a web tab.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It is not clear at all.